# GDM login screen only appears after switching virtual console

Tags: gdm3

I have a fairly stock Ubuntu 19.10 installation (gdm3, Gnome 3.34.2). On reboot (after the luks password screen) I just get a solid coloured screen but with no username or other content.

I can get to the proper login screen by switching virtual consoles (ctrl-alt-F2 and then back with ctrl-alt-F1). All is normal from that point.

It's a minor issue, but a bit annoying just the same. I think it started after I tested out the mate-desktop package, and then removed it. I had to remove a few other mate-*** packages, and something might have gone awry.

Anyone know how I can put the GDM login back to its original state?

Comment: FWIW I got a similar issue on my Arch desktop for quite some time now. Only instead of the "solid coloured screen" I can see the first virtual terminal, including systemd startup logs while booting, and the login prompt once systemd finishes booting. Switching virtual consoles and then back to VT1 triggers the login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Arch. What "resolved" it for me was one of these two commands (not sure which, I ran both), as described [in this comment](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1837552#p1837552) and [the one below](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1837652#p1837652):

```
dbus-launch gsettings reset org.gnome.clocks world-clocks
mv ~/.config/dconf/user{,~}
```

The first one simply resets the clock settings, the second one resets all user settings. This also means I've lost all my Gnome settings (I still have the backup though), including keyboard shortcuts, themes, desktop backgrounds, etc. But those I can re-create relatively easily.